# How to implement generics struct correctly

Tags: generics, rust

I am new to Rust, and try to implement Rectangle generic type. The following code gives compile error "move occurs because `self.w` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait". How can I fix this and is there a better way to do it?

```
struct Rectangle <T>{
    w : T,
    h : T 
}

impl<T:std::ops::Mul + std::ops::MulAssign + std::ops::Mul<Output = T>> Rectangle<T>{
    fn get_area(&self) -> T{
        return self.w * self.h;
    }

    fn scale(&mut self, scale:T) {
        self.w *= scale;
        self.h *= scale;
    }

    fn new(w:T, h:T) -> Rectangle<T> {
        return Rectangle{
            w:w,
            h:h
        };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let rect = Rectangle::new(1.2, 3.4);
    let area = rect.get_area();
    println!("Rectangle Area {area}");
}
```

Comment: It depends on what you *want* out of the types. Is there a reason `Rectangle` is even generic, and not (say) a rectangle with `f64` dimensions? Regardless, if you want to be able to copy or clone a data structure, you need to require an implementation of (respectively) `Copy` or `Clone`, which is what the error message is telling you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to add `+ Copy` to the list of traits you want T  to implement:

```
impl <T: ... + Copy> Rectangle {
             ^^^^^^
```

But I find keeping track of those long traits for numeric types to be painful, and so I usually introduce an umbrella trait. In your case it would look something like:

```
trait Field: std::ops::Mul + std::ops::MulAssign + std::ops::Mul<Output = Self> + Copy {}
impl <T:std::ops::Mul + std::ops::MulAssign + std::ops::Mul<Output = Self> + Copy> Field for T {}
```

Then you can just write:

```
impl <T:Field> Rectangle {
 ...
}
```